# How to remove testers from Testflight Public Link effectively freeing testers cap

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, testflight-public-link

We use Testflight Public Link groups to test several different builds of our app by distributing the links for our closed beta-testing community. Right now we have 2 groups. However it seems we have reached the cap of 10000 available testers and we don't know how to reduce this number.

Should we delete testing groups completely and create new ones? Should we deactivate some of our old builds (we remove old builds from the testing groups but we are not deactivating them completely)? Maybe other solutions?

We are looking for ways to free up some testing seats, but Apple documentation is too brief and is not explaining any details.